# Nested URL Routing in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-routing, gatsby

To go to, a `competition page` i'm using in `Gatsby` this function, to go to that page:

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  if (page.path.match(/^\/competition/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/competition/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
 }
```

from `competition page` i'm returning `Game component`:

```
 return <Game path="/competition/:id" myid={ props.id }/>
```

then inside `Game component` i'm rendering a button to go to channel page:

```
 <span className={style.button}>
     <Link to={'/competition/'+this.props.myid+'/'+rowdata['GameName']}/>
 </span>
```

here i don't know how to go to `channel page` i have inside `src/pages` and keeping my url like in the code: `/competition/'+myid+'/'+GameName`

is my approach correct? **i'm open to other solutions**

Update :
i can accept a **url** like this:

```
<span className={style.button}>
     <Link to={'/competition/'+this.props.myid+'/channel'}/>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with gatsby, but it seems like you need to be stricter with the regexp of the root path of your API.

```
if (page.path.match(/^\/competition/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/competition/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
```

currently, the above matches '/competition', '/competition9302n', '/competition/903n/channel'... basically anything STARTING with '/competition'

If you want to treat '/competition/' as a separate path from '/competition/some_id_here/channel', then you need to define two (at the very least, a stricter root path) distinct paths/routes.

ex.

```
if (page.path.match(/^\/competition\/[0-9a-z].*$/i)) { // this will match only '/competition/<some_id_here>'
    page.matchPath = "/competition/*"
    createPage(page)
  } else if (page.path.match(/^\/competition\/[0-9a-z].*\/channel$/i)) {//this will match only '/competition/<some_id_here>/channel'
  }
```

Comment: now the only link working is `/competition`.. '/competition/<some_id_here>' is not working plus '/competition/<some_id_here>/channel' 404 page returned

Comment: What are your 'ids' made up of? Only letters and numbers? That regexp is not perfect, you have to tailor it to your data needs. Also, those checks are only for the 'if' conditionals, make sure the 'page.matchPath' is mapping to the correct regexp as well.

Comment: my ids are only letters

Comment: Could you post all of the 'if' conditionals please. Also, I need more specific information. What is not working? Are the pages not rendering? Are the 'if' conditionals working--the program passes into the code block--but the code inside isn't firing?